# A jpg upload triggers: File Not Allowed

Tags: file-uploads, error, file-manager, files, uploads

After upgrading to 2.10.3, my client can no longer upload anything via the File Manager - not even a vanilla 24kb jpg.

"File not Allowed" appears in red letters in the modal window where the file is chosen.

I've double-checked the mime type locally:

```
199701AD.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
```

And this is obviously in-line with EE's default settings for allowed files.

I've noticed that the file is thrown away and the error is thrown after the file is uploaded. I've tried a variety of files, all have the same result. The upload directory permissions are 777 (for the purposes of debugging this.)

Comment: does the file open OK locally in Photoshop or similar?

Comment: Are the permissions for the thumbnail directory the same? You using GD or ImageMagick to create thumbnails?

Comment: @StevenGrant - yes the file opens great everywhere, is about as normal and un-special as it gets.

Comment: @JohnHenryDonovan It had not been, but now that it's also 777 I am not noticing a change.

Answer (score 0):

[File Info for 2.10.0](https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/fileinfo-in-2-10-0)

Apparently an entire config file had changed format (mimes.php) for version 2.10.

I'm not entirely sure how I didn't overwrite the old one, because this should have happened in at least 1 of my fallbacks, but I had the old one so technically no files were whitelisted.